# Reinterpreting array of 8bit values as standard complex values?

Tags: c++

I receive an array of complex values (16 bit integer) into a buffer.  In the past I've handled the situation like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int16_t re;
    int16_t im;
} complex_16_t;

uint8_t * buffer;

// after receiving data into buffer pointer
foo((complex_16_t *) data, length);
```

I now have to use the `std::complex` data type as the input to my function `foo` instead of my own structure.  Can I go about this using `std::complex` without creating a second buffer and copying data?

Comment: Which specialization of `complex`?

Comment: Your old code already makes some serious platform-dependent assumptions as to the packing of `complex_16_t` and endianness. Do you *really* want to perpetuate that further?

Comment: Is there a good (fast) way around this problem that is also portable?  Because of a new requirement to use libraries that use `std::complex` my data has to be handled as an array of them.  I don't know what you mean by what specialization of `complex`.  Right now I'm building with gcc 4.8.3 on 64bit fedora 20.  However that will change as things are updated and this software is built on other platforms using similar compilers.

Comment: @tylerjw: "I don't know what you mean by what specialization" - `std::complex` is a template. You need to specialise it as `complex<float>`, `complex<double>`, or `complex<long double>` to get a complex type.

Comment: I'm using `std::complex<int16_t>`.

Comment: That's not one of the expected argument types. It might work for your compiler, but expect some problems with e.g. `.arg()` which would return one of {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} !

Comment: I have implemented all the methods I need to perform on the data, I'm not using the standard methods such as arg(), conj(), ...  I was mostly concerned about the cast not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not portably. `std::complex` is only specified for floating-point types, not `int16_t`.

If your library does support that specialisation as a non-standard extension, then hopefully it will also provide the same guarantee as for the supported types: that reinterpreting an array of the underlying type as an array of half as many complex types works as you'd like it to. If that's the case, then your code should work with `complex<int16_t>` as well as it does now with your type.

Comment: The library I'm now interacting with uses `std::complex<int16_t>` as one of it's base types for sample data (Intel `IPPLIB`).

Comment: @tylerjw: If that library supports the non-standard specialisation with the same guarantees as the standard ones, then it should work. I've no idea whether or not it does.

Comment: Ok, I tested it and it works in my environment.  I just am not comfortable enough with `c++` to trust this.  I used `reinterpret_cast<std::complex<int16_t> *>(buffer)` to do the cast in  `c++`.